# How to list all the Activity names of the installed packages or applications on the device without using AAPT

Tags: android, python, shell

I am new to Python and Android and got struck at this where i need to launch the application on the device through command line

```
adb shell am start -n Package-Name /.Activity-Name
```

Package Names got listed out using `adb shell pm list packages`
Similarly, I would like to list all the Activity names of the installed packages on the device

NOTE : Can we list the Activity names without using AAPT [Android Asset Packaging Tool] ?
I have looked in to few posts in which they were using this so called AAPT

Comment: Not sure what Python has to do with this question..

Answer (score 0):

Try Apktool or AXMLPrinter, they can decompile the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the apk.Then, parse this file to get all exported activities your self.

Google for details of this tools.